# How to display an ul in li inline?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'd like to know if it is possible to display a second li-element inline in a first li-element.

The structure is like:

```
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li>some styling
            <ul>
               <li>this element should be displayed inline</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS rules for first `ul` is working to display it inline in the `div` by using `display: inline-block`.
I thought it would also work for using it for the second li-element with `.one ul li ul { display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Add some code snippet

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/0awgty9v/). Note `.one ul` matches all `ul` which are descendants of `.one`. So `.one ul` should suffice. If you want to specify all the path use child selectors: `.one > ul > li > ul`.

Comment: Hello, here is what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/0awgty9v/1/

Comment: @John How should that fiddle look like?

Comment: @Oriol the yellow box should be in the red one. they both have the same width. ...like that http://jsfiddle.net/0awgty9v/2/

Comment: `.one > ul ul { padding:0 }`

Comment: thanks but this is not the issue. the issue is to integrate that content into the red. for example when i get some list entries from a db i would like to limit and scroll just in the red box. with that soiution the entire list would be like: http://jsfiddle.net/0awgty9v/3/ just over the red box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you were asking for vertical or horizontal scrolling so here are both examples.

Here is an up and down scroll:

```css
.one {height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: #EEEEEE;}
.one ul {display: inline-block; list-style: none;padding:0;}
.one ul li {width: 150px; height: 100px; background-color: red;overflow:scroll;}
.one ul li ul li {width: 150px; height:30px; background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li>I scroll up and down
            <ul>
               <li>1 ...</li>
                <li>2 ...</li>
                <li>3 ..</li>
                <li>4 ..</li>
                <li>5 ..</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>some other random list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a left to right scroll:

```css
.one {height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: #EEEEEE;}
.one ul {display: inline-block; list-style: none; padding:0;}
.one ul li {width: 150px; background-color: red; overflow:scroll;}
.one ul li ul li {width: 150px; height:30px; background-color: yellow;}
.one ul ul {display: flex;float: left;}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li>I scroll this way ->
            <ul>
               <li>1 ...</li>
                <li>2 ...</li>
                <li>3 ..</li>
                <li>4 ..</li>
                <li>5 ..</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>some other random list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.one {
  display: block;
}

.one > ul {
  display: block;
}

.one > ul > li {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.one > ul > li > ul, .one > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Inline</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>Inline</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Block</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```